# Modelling access restrictions to records

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

Looking for some collective wisdom from data-design gurus...

I'm in the process of writing a web-based game (a web app essentially). The game dynamics require access checks before granting/denying achievements.

My games needs a fine control who/when can be granted access to certain achievements. These achievement requirements vary and could be a combination of any one of these:

- User must view something (there is a table that stores this visit info)
- User must wait until access is grated (e.g. record is accessible 2 weeks after account creation)
- User must have responded to an event (e.g. message)
- User must've answered a question (e.g. in-game vote)

However I can't hard-code these as the game allows custom "universes" created for each game-master. Thus each game-master should be able to create/change ways achievements are granted in his/her "universe".

I'm having difficulties coming up with a database design that would allow to store these restrictions for an achievement record. Is there any good general design pattern for storing this kind of info? Any helpful books, websites?

Any thoughts, suggestions are welcome.

*PS. I've tried Google-ing but most hits returned are about how to control access to databases not how to design tables that would store this information.*

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is modelling state.  The most common way to model state is with a state transition table.

```
            View something | Wait     | Respond | Answer
            ----------------------------------------
User 1        view action  |          | resp act|
User 2                     | wait act |         |
User 3                     |          |         | answer act
```

and so forth.

Edited to add: The table only holds state information.  Your code has to know how to set the state table and what to do when a state or combination of states is completed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I understand your design, my initial idea was very close to this. I had a table of AchievementRequirements. But it did not allow me to have multi-part achievements like (must view X,Y,Z). Which could be thought of as "view X AND view Y AND view Z". Which also bring up the question how to store AND/OR-ed achievement requirements. For example: (view W AND view Y) OR answer G. I'm having difficulty coming up with generic design to be able to store such things in a database.

Comment: You have to think in states.  In your first example, the action of view X is view Y.  The action of view Y is view Z.  The action of view Z is view action.  Of course, you would have to deal with the permutations of X, Y, and Z, so that you're not order dependent. In your second example with the OR, you still deal with states.

Comment: I think we're thinking of this from different perspectives. I'm trying to model modifiable requirements for an achievement, rather than storing state of an achievement for each user. My code would then do a live check that the stored requirements are met before granting access to something (e.g. achievement). If the requirements are not met (or have been changed since), then no access.

Comment: I'm already storing state in various tables (pages visited, polls answered, msgs replied to). What I find difficult is modeling access restrictions based on multiple criteria. E.g. to access an achievement (able to view something or whatever), I check the table of requirements for this(which could be to view X, respond to msg M, and only 2 weeks past registering account). Once I can store these requirements along, I can write the code that goes through all of these requirements to check them.